# Django Models compare 2 model and filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i want to get the model details with corresponding another model

my models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    DeviceName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    Camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CameraId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Device"

class Camera(models.Model):
    CameraId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CameraId')
    CameraName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Camera"
```

i want my camera details

that is the camera details that not saved in Device foreign key (means the camera details that not used the foreign key for device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **`device__isnull=True`** filter (Ref: Django [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) lookup)

```
camera_without_devices = Camera.objects.filter(device__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the `Camera` objects where the related model (here `device`) is `None`/`NULL`:

```
Camera.objects.filter(device=None)
```

This wokrs because Django will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so in case there is no device present, it will add one row with `NULL` as value for the columns related to the `Device`.

Comment: thank you..  This  method also working .  :)  .. i  cant add  tick for 2 answer.. sorry ..
 This Answer also works  :)